# Elegant application of attribute set/get or method to several objects of same type

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to achieve the following without using loops or comprehensions (at least explicitly) as I believe this is more elegant, especially considering the degree of nested attributes I am using.

Say I have an object nested like so: `a.b.c.d.e`, where `e` is of type `NodeList`. `NodeList` holds a list of `Node` objects internally. You can use `a.b.c.d.e.all()` to get this list of all objects.

`Node` has a member `val` that I would like to set on all nodes in `e`.
I want syntax like this to work: `a.b.c.d.e.all().val = <val>`. Is there a way I can implement the `all()` method such that this is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to achieve this by implementing:
`a.b.c.d.e.all(lambda x: x.val = <val>)` where `all` applies the lambda to each `Node`.

I think this solution is quite nice. Not ideal. If you have any other ideas, please let me know. Thanks.